# Proper Memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, struct, hashtable, allocation

I have the following construction:

```
typedef struct bucket {
    char *key;
    ENTRY *data;
    struct bucket *next;
} bucket;

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    bucket **table;
} hash_table;
```

But I have no idea how to allocate memory for that. I tried:

```
hash_table* ht = malloc(sizeof(hash_table)*101);
```

in order to create a hashtable for 101 entries but it din't work! Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: why bucket **table, not bucket *table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. Assuming this is C, you probably want to make a function:

```
 hash_table* init_table(size_t size) {
     size_t i;
     hash_table* ht = (hash_table*)malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
     if (ht == NULL) return NULL;
     ht->size = size;
     ht->table = (bucket**)malloc(sizeof(bucket*)*size);
     if (ht->table == NULL) {
         free(ht);
         return NULL;
     }
     for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
         ht->table[i] = NULL;
     }
     return ht;
 }
```

You might need some other fields in that struct.

If you wanted to be tricky, and never realloc the bucket, you can do this:

```
 hash_table* init_table(size_t size) {
     hash_table* ht = (hash_table*)malloc(sizeof(hash_table)+sizeof(bucket)*size);
     if (ht == NULL) return NULL;
     ht->size = size;
     ht->table = (bucket**)(ht+1);
     for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
         ht->table[i] = NULL;
     }
     return ht;
 }
```

EDIT: I fixed my bucket* table's to bucket**

EDIT2: I've gotten rid of the memsets and added error checking for malloc.

Comment: Wouldn't "ht->bucket = (bucket*)(ht+1)" only work when "sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*)" and no memory allignment is necessary (packaged struct)? Or is that a given?

Comment: ht+1 takes you to the hash_table after the first hash_table and thus points to the byte directly after the last bytes of the struct (+ padding needed for alignment purposes).

Comment: unwind, you are correct. I didn't notice the "table" was an array of pointers.

Comment: your "trick" won't work. i would strongly discourage from that. there is no guarantee you've got the right alignment. and also, it should be sizeof(bucket*)*size in the malloc call

Comment: This is still broken. The table member of the hash_table struct is pointer to pointer, not just a pointer. It is supposed to just hold an array of pointers to buckets, NOT the buckets themselves. Buckets are allocated on insert. The code makes no sense.

Comment: There are numerious problems with this answer from casting malloc to using memset improperly to just plain not working at all.  Please accept @unwind's answer or at least unaccept this answer.

Comment: Unwind and ltib: It is sizeof(bucket*)*size in the malloc call. Robert: what is wrong with the memset?

Comment: ht+1 must have the right alignment. It is identical to &ht[1]. I have compiled and run this code in Visual Studio. It work perfectly and with no warnings.

Comment: You are using memset to initialize pointer values assuming that the representation for a null pointer is all-bits zero which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Granted. I've never worked on an architecture with weird pointers. Since I am still checked, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't make sense to allocate all 101 (or however many) buckets upfront, you'd typically allocate them one at a time, when inserting new data into the table.

It *does* make sense to pre-allocate the hash array, which will have a fixed size, but that is an *array of bucket pointers*, not an array of buckets, so some of the answers are wrong.

You'd have something like this, to create a an empty hash table, with a fixed-size bucket array:

```
hash_table * hash_table_new(size_t capacity)
{
  size_t i;

  hash_table *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
  t->size = capacity;
  t->bucket = malloc(t->size * sizeof *t->bucket);
  for(i = 0; i < t->size; i++)
    t->bucket[i] = NULL;
  return t;
}
```

This code:

- Allocates a hash_table structure to hold the table
- Initializes it's size with indicated capacity
- Allocates an array of bucket pointers of the proper length
- Makes sure each bucket pointer is NULL (which cannot properly be done with memset(), as it's not safe to assume that "all bits zero" is the way NULL looks in memory)
- Uses `sizeof` whenever possible, but not on types, so no parenthesis
- Doesn't cast the return value of `malloc()`, since that is never a good idea in C
- Doesn't check the return value of malloc(), of course you should do that in real code

A second function would be needed to do an actual hash insert, which will then need to allocate a new bucket, compute the hash value from the key, pick the proper location in the hash table's array, and insert the new entry there.

Comment: i like how you take the sizeof of the expressions, and not of the type. nice style. +1

Comment: This is the only way to use sizeof. :) *Huge* pet peeve of mine, with sprinkles on top.

Comment: @unwind: So many good practices (good sizeof usage, not casting malloc, NULL/memset trap) and well structured code but you don't check the return value of malloc?  If you don't want to clutter the example with error handling at least mention in your list that it should be performed in the real code.

Comment: I'd use calloc for the bucket allocation, though

Answer (score 0):

The `hash_table` will always be only `sizeof(hash_table)` bytes big. The `table` element is a pointer to an array of poiinters to `bucket` elements. So you'd need something like this:

```
hash_table* ht = malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
ht->size = 101;
ht->table = malloc(sizeof(bucket*)*ht->size);
```

But I suspect that there may be some initialization method that comes with that, and you could then do something like this:

```
hash_table* ht = alloc_hash_table(101);
```

Anyway, I'm kind of rusty in C, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: He has a "bucket **table;", i.e. an array of pointers to buckets (probably to avoid allocating buckets until they needed). So it should be "ht->table = malloc(sizeof(bucket*)*ht->size);"

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things worong with your typedef's.  Assuming your using MSVC.

An easy way to declare the types you have here would be something like;

This typedef includes the _type {} type, *ptype; format which declares the type and the pointer to your custom type all at the same time.  If you see down in hash_table, your are able to use pbucket *table, which eliminates the extra *** in your code and can help when doing dynamic allocation (help so mucah as to keep your head straight about what your allocating etc..).  Your original typedef, if you look had typedef struct bucket {} bucket;, you need to at least modify one of the two "bucket" names you have there when you specify your typedef.

You also need to cast if your using C++ build settings, if using plain C you may not need the cast, so your malloc line would be (with the following typedef changes I made);

```
hash_table* ht = (phash_table) malloc(sizeof(hash_table)*101);
```

Either way, this snippet should work for you;

```
typedef struct _bucket {    
    char *key;    
    void *data;    
    _bucket *next;
} bucket, *pbucket;

typedef struct _hash_table {    
    size_t size;    
    pbucket *table;
}hash_table, *phash_table;
```